# Getting all the style properties using JQuery. Basically I want an equivalent of getComputedStyle() and I dont want to handle cross-browser stuff

Tags: javascript, jquery, styles

I would like to get the currentStyle/computedStyle object and I dont want to manually check for the type of browser. (I wanted to get rid of cross-browser handling that is why I came to Jquery).
Actually I want the style object returning all the style-property: value map.
Please help.

Comment: Do you need all the styles, or just a select few?  The approach would be very different depending on this.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558426/getcomputedstyle-or-cssmap-to-get-every-style-declaration and http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html, wrap the cross-browser code `getStyle` function in a jquery plugin or custom selector to isolate it from your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is a soultion for a similiar problem offered by [Keith Bentrup](https://stackoverflow.com/users/109826/keith-bentrup): [jQuery CSS plugin that returns computed style of element to pseudo clone that element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004475)

He used a list of attributes from Firebug and created a computed style object with jQuery to be able to clone styles from one object to another:

```
jQuery.fn.css2 = jQuery.fn.css;
jQuery.fn.css = function() {
    if (arguments.length) return jQuery.fn.css2.apply(this, arguments);
    var attr = ['font-family','font-size','font-weight','font-style','color',
        'text-transform','text-decoration','letter-spacing','word-spacing',
        'line-height','text-align','vertical-align','direction','background-color',
        'background-image','background-repeat','background-position',
        'background-attachment','opacity','width','height','top','right','bottom',
        'left','margin-top','margin-right','margin-bottom','margin-left',
        'padding-top','padding-right','padding-bottom','padding-left',
        'border-top-width','border-right-width','border-bottom-width',
        'border-left-width','border-top-color','border-right-color',
        'border-bottom-color','border-left-color','border-top-style',
        'border-right-style','border-bottom-style','border-left-style','position',
        'display','visibility','z-index','overflow-x','overflow-y','white-space',
        'clip','float','clear','cursor','list-style-image','list-style-position',
        'list-style-type','marker-offset'];
    var len = attr.length, obj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) 
        obj[attr[i]] = jQuery.fn.css2.call(this, attr[i]);
    return obj;
}
```

This seems to do exactly what you are looking for.

There are also a couple of plugins for that:

1. http://github.com/peol/jquery-computed-style
2. http://www.jupiterit.com/news/get-multiple-computed-styles-fast-with-the-curstyles-jquery-plugin

Comment: Even though this is accepted but I feel it would be better if we had something like a cloneStyle function that would copy styles from one element to other.