# How to get the computed width of an element's border?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How can I get the computed border width of a HTML element in Javascript? (Independent of where and how the border is specified.)

Comment: Can the four sides have different widths or will they be set constantly to the same width?

Comment: @Pekka: Yes, they can have different widths.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want something like [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle), but that's not a 100% cross-browser function - you'll have to [work a little harder for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558426/getcomputedstyle-or-cssmap-to-get-every-style-declaration/2561294#2561294).