# How do I export dom values of element to css file equivalent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have element that are being dynamically updated and I want to generate a css file which contains the rendered styles for that element. Is there anything that does this? Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558426/getcomputedstyle-or-cssmap-to-get-every-style-declaration

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing I know of in jQuery or JavaScript that does this intrinsically.  However, if you just want it for yourself and not for dynamically creating stylesheets, then I recommend Firefox and the Firebug plugin.  This will show you the CSS live and you can modify and export it, as well.

Answer (score 0):

[getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM%3awindow.getComputedStyle) gives you the computed style of an element:

```
window.getComputedStyle($("#my_element").get(0))
```

Comment: more specifically, `window.getComputedStyle(element).cssText` but in IE it's `element.currentStyle.cssText`