# Resetting all CSS styles for a widget

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a Javascript widget that uses many custom styles. When a user places the widget on his page, the user's page always affects the widget's styling. Is there a way to prevent this?

For example, if I have an input box in my widget:

```
<input id="#special-input" />
```

And the user has styles that override the input:

```
input { width: 500px; }
```

Then, the user's page will override the width of the input box. There are so many ways that a user can change the style of the widget that I cannot account for all of them. For example, for an input, I would have to account for border, shadowing, width, height, etc. and any other ways that a user could style the page and affect my widget.

Comment: Way to broad. Some examples of what is happening please.

Comment: Declare the styles inline: `<div style="width:100px">`. Then end-users would have to explicitly use !important to override them.

Comment: Another tip: Use specific id's and classes that are unlikely to be used by other web pages.

Comment: Edited. Even if I declare the styles inline, there are many CSS attributes that would indirectly affect my widget's CSS. What if the user sets a input:hover CSS attribute which ends up affecting my widget? There are so many things to worry about.

Comment: This might be a bit overkill, but it's the only thing I could think of off the top of my head. You could use `window.getComputedStyle` on the specific elements of your widget,  loop through the results, then clear all of the styles it finds. Once that has been done, apply your styles and you should be good to go. Just make sure to target your specific elements so you don't end up wiping the entire page clean...

Comment: If it's something people include in their sites you'll probably have to use an iframe. If it's meant as plugin/framework/library then use custom classes and style against reset css styles. If they overwrite them, then they probably know what they're doing.

Answer (score 0):

To piggy back off my comment above, you could do something like below. (completely untested and quickly thrown together) This uses Jquery, but I'm sure you can figure out how to modify it if you use another library or pure JS.

```
var allStyles = ["azimuth","background","backgroundAttachment","backgroundColor","backgroundImage","backgroundPosition","backgroundRepeat","border","borderBottom","borderBottomColor","borderBottomStyle","borderBottomWidth","borderCollapse","borderColor","borderLeft","borderLeftColor","borderLeftStyle","borderLeftWidth","borderRight","borderRightColor","borderRightStyle","borderRightWidth","borderSpacing","borderStyle","borderTop","borderTopColor","borderTopStyle","borderTopWidth","borderWidth","bottom","captionSide","clear","clip","color","content","counterIncrement","counterReset","cssFloat","cue","cueAfter","cueBefore","cursor","direction","display","elevation","emptyCells","font","fontFamily","fontSize","fontSizeAdjust","fontStretch","fontStyle","fontVariant","fontWeight","height","left","letterSpacing","lineHeight","listStyle","listStyleImage","listStylePosition","listStyleType","margin","marginBottom","marginLeft","marginRight","marginTop","markerOffset","marks","maxHeight","maxWidth","minHeight","minWidth","orphans","outline","outlineColor","outlineStyle","outlineWidth","overflow","padding","paddingBottom","paddingLeft","paddingRight","paddingTop","page","pageBreakAfter","pageBreakBefore","pageBreakInside","pause","pauseAfter","pauseBefore","pitch","pitchRange","playDuring","position","quotes","richness","right","size","speak","speakHeader","speakNumeral","speakPunctuation","speechRate","stress","tableLayout","textAlign","textDecoration","textIndent","textShadow","textTransform","top","unicodeBidi","verticalAlign","visibility","voiceFamily","volume","whiteSpace","widows","width","wordSpacing","zIndex"];

    $.each(allStyles, function(key, value){
        if ($this.css(value) !== undefined){
            $this.css(key, "")
        }
    });
```

***NOTE*** My above post is modified from this answer on another topic. Just wanted to give credit to @Matrym... [getComputedStyle (or) $.css(map) <-- to get every style declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558426/getcomputedstyle-or-cssmap-to-get-every-style-declaration)