# can I use console/alert/some-other-means to read out ALL CSS properties at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to debug a site on iPad. On desktop an element shows, on iPad it's missing.

**Question**:
Is there a way to output all CSS in one statement similar to

```
console.log( $('element').attr('class') );
```

or is the only way to find the faulty property to go through all CSS-rules one by one?

```
console.log( $('element').css('position') )
console.log( $('element').css('top') )
console.log( $('element').css('left') )
console.log( $('element').css('right') )
console.log( $('element').css('bottom') )
console.log( $('element').css('width') )
console.log( $('element').css('height') )
console.log( $('element').css('display') )
... you get the point...
```

Thanks for input

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151558/how-to-get-all-the-calculated-styles-of-an-element-with-jquery

Comment: Check the first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element

Comment: Install FireBug Lite, so you can use it on an iPad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle):

> getComputedStyle() gives the final used values of all the CSS
>   properties of an element.

Supported in every modern browser (including IE9).

A simple example:

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle($('element').get(0), null);
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Pbe4N/)

Comment: And of course, to use a jQuery selector: `document.defaultView.getComputedStyle($("element")[0], null)`

Answer (score 2):

It's a lot easier to use some tools to remotely inspect the page on the iPad. iOS 6 will get this built in, but that doesn't helpt much now. If you're on a Mac you can try out [iWebInspector](http://www.iwebinspector.com/) along with the iOS SDK. If not, you can check out WeInRe.

1. Install [iOS SDK](https://developer.apple.com) (free) and [iWebInspector](http://www.iwebinspector.com/)
2. Open iWebInspector
3. Click "Open iOS Simulator"
4. Switch to iPad through the menu Hardware -> Device -> iPad
5. Open Safari and go the page you want to debug
6. Click "Load from Safari" back in iWebInspector, and chose the page
7. You should now get the WebKit debugger inside iWebInspector

[image]

[WeInRe](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/) (Webkit Inspector Remote) should work on any platform without the need for iOS SDK. It doesn't work as well as the real debuggers, since it just injects a scripts and only has access to what you get through javascript. But it's a lot easier than printing out all the css programatically ;) Sometimes WeInRe doesn't catch changes to the DOM after you've looked at an element. So wait until the DOM is in the state you want to look at before expanding the parent element. WeInRe is kindly hosted by PhoneGap: [debug.phonegap.com](http://debug.phonegap.com/), or can be installed on your computer http://phonegap.github.com/weinre/

Comment: and I can use this with HTML5/CSS/Javascript? Cool!

Comment: @frequent Exactly ;) Just like Firebug/Webkit Inspector. But remotely, so you inspect on the device from your computer.

Answer (score 1):

jquery .css() works better than .getComputedStyle as it accounts for browser difference (and is based on getComputedStyle itself), see http://api.jquery.com/css/

see [how to get all the calculated styles of an element with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151558/how-to-get-all-the-calculated-styles-of-an-element-with-jquery) and credit the answer there :)

Comment: I don't really get this. First you say that `.css()` is better, and then point to an answer that uses simple `getComputedStyle()`. Also, browser differences don't really matter here, he wants something that works on iPad. I downvote because your answer says nothing but a link to another answer (which should be a flag/comment).

Comment: the accepted answer to that question doesn't say to use getComputedStyle() but .css(), anyway I appreciate your suggestion to leave a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small plugin that adds $.fn.computedCSS() you can use to get what others have already suggested:

Code:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.computedCSS = function() {
        var elem = $(this)[0];
        var styles = window.getComputedStyle(elem);
        var computed = {};  
        for (key in styles) {
            if (!key.match(/^\d+$/) && typeof styles[key] !== 'function') {
                computed[key] = styles[key];   
            }
        }
        return computed;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/Kd6xR/